# Ajax error value return null

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I have a function in ajax :

```
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("FiltraLevatamento", "Consulta")",
                    data: JSON.stringify(jsn),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {

                            result(data); 


                        $("#modalboxProcessa").modal("hide");

                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, txtStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $("#modalboxProcessa").modal("hide");
                        $("#modalboxErro2").modal("show");

                    }
                });
```

In my local machine works properly only when I publish in the server error in ajax .

Can anyone tell me what is the problem ? I have pretty much the same ajax only returning me other than data, and is running fine .

Comment: Open firebug or chrome developer tool and look into the error message

Comment: What is the error? Is the resource deployed/mapped on the server?

Comment: That's the problem presents the 404 , already put to detail the error, but does not show anything. Ja goes straight to the " error "

Comment: If it presents a 404, that's the error. Go to the URL via your browser and you should see it. Figure that out and your problem is solved.